# Regular expression for 7 digits followed by an optional 3 letters

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I'm new to regular expressions, and I'm trying to validate receipt numbers in our database with a regular expression.

Our receipts can come in the following formats:

- 0123456 (Manditory seven digits, no more, no less)
- 0126456a (Manditory seven digits with one letter a-z)
- 0126456ab (Manditory seven digits with two letters a-z)
- 0126456abc (Manditory seven digits with three letters a-z)

I've tried using a bunch of different regex combinations, but none seem to work. Right now I have:

```
(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)([a-z])?([a-z])?([a-z])?
```

But this is allowing for more than seven digits, and is allowing more than 3 letters.

Here is my VBA function within Access 2010 that will validate the expression:

```
Function ValidateReceiptNumber(ByVal sReceipt As String) As Boolean

    If (Len(sReceipt) = 0) Then
        ValidateReceiptNumber = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim oRegularExpression     As RegExp

'   Sets the regular expression object
    Set oRegularExpression = New RegExp

    With oRegularExpression
'   Sets the regular expression pattern
        .Pattern = "(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)([a-z])?([a-z])?([a-z])?"

'   Ignores case
        .IgnoreCase = True

'       Test Receipt string
        ValidateReceiptNumber = .Test(sReceipt)

    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to use anchors at the ends. Further your regex can be simplified to: -

```
^\d{7}[a-z]{0,3}$
```

- `\d{7}` matches exactly `7 digits`. You don't need to use `\d` 7
  times for that.
- `{0,3}` creates a range, and matches 0 to 3 repetition of preceding pattern,
- `Caret(^)` matches the start of the line
- `Dollar($)` matches the end of the line.

Answer (score 6):

`^(\d){7}[a-z]{0,3}$` might work well. The `^` and `$` will match the start and end of line respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to make sure you are matching the entire string, by using anchors.

```
^(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)([a-z])?([a-z])?([a-z])?$
```

You can also simplify the regex. First, you don't need all those parentheses.

```
^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d[a-z]?[a-z]?[a-z]?$
```

Also, you can use limited repetition, to prevent repeating yourself.

```
^\d{7}[a-z]{0,3}$
```

Where `{7}` means 'exactly 7 times', and `{0,3}` means '0-3 times'.